# How to read data from local JSON file and show it in UItableview in iOS 11 swift 4

Tags: ios, xcode8, swift4

Need to develop a single view application with tableview getting image, name and description from a local json file.
Any help would be great

Comment: In Swift 4 you can use `JSONDecoder`

Answer (score 0):

To get data from local json file use below lines of code

```
 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "countries", ofType: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: URL(fileURLWithPath: path), options: .alwaysMapped)
                //parse data here
                //If you are using SwiftyJSON use below commanded line
               // let jsonObj = try JSON(data: data)

            } catch let error {
                print("parse error: \(error.localizedDescription)")
            }
        } else {
            print("Invalid filename/path.")
        }
    }
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: Error: use of unresolved identifier JSON.\

Comment: This will not compile if SwiftyJSON is not installed (not everybody uses it and it's obsolete in Swift 4 in many cases) and why do you create the file URL although there is `url(forResource` in `Bundle`?

Comment: If your are using SwiftyJSON you can use that commanded line otherwise parse it into JSON data @Ayush